# Object to Array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im trying to convert JS Object to an Array but Array after conversion is undefined.

I initially have JSON but from what I have read it is automatically parsed into JS Object (when I try to parse it, I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1). Also when I `console.log(typeof cityList)` I get Object.

Initial JSON goes like this:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  }
    ]
```

I import JSON like this: `import cityList from './city.list.json';`

I use this code to convert:

```
const cityListArray = Object.values(cityList);
```

If I `console.log(cityListArray)` I get undefined.

I also tried: `const cityListArray = Object.keys(cityList).map(i => cityList[i])` but result is the same.

Im not sure where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show how you're trying to export the array, that's key to the question.

Comment: try to console.log your import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything, since the JSON object is already an array.

You shouldn't check if something is an array with `typeof` since it returns `"object"` for arrays.

```
const a = [];
typeof a; // "object"
```

You should use the `Array.isArray()` method instead.